# How to return related objects from Azure AD using Microsoft Graph

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I could not find the answer to this question so far. I'd really appreciate any help.

I am using Microsoft Graph to get the list of users from Azure AD. This what works so far:

This request returns a list of users using specified query:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/?$top=999&$select=department,id,displayname
```

This request returns manager for indicated user:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{iser id}/manager
```

Is there a way to return a manager for each user in the first request? If I write

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/?$top=999&$select=department,id,displayname,manager
```

I don't get an error, but I also don't see the manager. Any advice?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$expand` parameter to expand the manager property of the user objects.

This is **very well documented** [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/query_parameters#expand-parameter):

> Note: Not all relationships and resources support the $expand query
>   parameter. For example, you can expand the directReports, **manager**, and
>   memberOf relationships on a **user**, but you cannot expand its events,
>   messages, or photo relationships. Not all resources or relationships
>   support using $select on expanded items.
>
> With Azure AD resources that derive from directoryObject, like user
>   and group, $expand is only supported for beta and typically returns a
>   maximum of 20 items for the expanded relationship.

Note the limitations and the requirement for using the `beta` version of API.

So your query at the end would be:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/?top=999&select=department,id,displayname&expand=manager`

Also note that with the `beta` version of the api there is no need to add the **$** for query options anymore.

**UPDATE**

Do not skip lines when reading. There are limits defined under `$expand` such as:

> With Azure AD resources that derive from directoryObject, like user
>   and group, $expand is only supported for beta and typically returns a
>   **maximum of 20 items for the expanded relationship**.

Comment: Thanks, astaykov,
Great to know about $
It still works fine on any individual user, but won't work on the list. Perhaps this is one of the limitations.
I tried both Graph Explorer and Postman...

Comment: well, I have tested it with /users/?expand=manager and it works! Using the **beta** version! Can you please confirm what exactly are you trying. By the way, in order to access user's manager you have to grant Users.ReadAll permission to the service principal / user.

Comment: Thanks, astaykov, it did work at the end. The issue was page size. When using "expand" I can only go up to 100 records per page. Not sure why I did not see it earlier.. must be Friday :)